# "Print PDF Letter for Contacts" missing from Contact Actions

Tags: pdf

There's a lot of reference to this but the 4.7 version I'm setting up has changed this action. How do you print a pdf letter for contacts in 4.7?

Answer (score 1):

Found it of course right after posting. The trick is to look in Actions for "Print/Merge Document"